# How can I create log for ADD-Adgroupmember results

Tags: powershell-4.0

Simple really, I have a PS script ready to go but I would like to pipe the results of adding 1000 names to an AD security group with Add-ADGroupMember. Problem is ADD-Adgroupmember doesn't return any results. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the call in a `try`/`catch` block:

```
$Group = Get-ADGroup "myGroup"
$Users = "habanagold","habanasilver","mrceo"
foreach($User in $Users){
    try {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User -ErrorAction Stop
        "$User added to $Group" | Out-File C:\path\to\output.log -Append
    } catch {
        "Failed to add $User to $Group" | Out-File C:\path\to\output.log -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did the task because of time constraints, but I will try this in a test environment when I can.